# Android table-like layout suggestion

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create a tricky layout like in the picture below.
[image]

Each square is a ImageView. The idea is that regardless of screen size or resolution layout that contains "1,2,3,4 and 5" fills parent by width and maintains the configuration like it the image above ("4" should be below and between "1" and "2", "5" below and between "2" and "3").

I have tried using two linear layouts with "weight" specified, tried using "Grid Layout", even the "Table Layout" but no luck - even if i get initial configuration right, it won't retain on different screen sizes.

How to achieve the layout like it the picture?

Comment: Use a relative layout and add an invisible view between 1 & 2 and an invisible view between 2 & 3 and align 4 and 5 accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout.This may be not a perfect solution,but I hope you get an idea :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an idea! :) All that's missing are weight values but your code is close to what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

What I did.
Steps 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 are very basic you can skip them if you know what to do ( is just opening your app files, and making the layout look the way you did as simply as possible.)

**Step 1 :**
Open Eclipse.

**Step 2 :**
Open your application
(In the package explorer, expand your app)

**Step 3 :**
Double click src, the package name, and then your Java File. (By default it will be called mainActivityJava, or whatever you named it) this opens your java file you should see your java file, leave it open.

**Step 4 :**
Go back to the package explorer, double click res, layout, then double click your layout name. (By default it should be main_activity.xml) you should now have both your layout and java file open, you can navigate between them by clicking on there names you can see them as tabs by each other.

**Step 5 :**
Open your XML file and if you look in the upper right corner you will see all the stuff in your layout. Delete everything in it except the layout at the top. ( by right clicking them, and then clicking delete.)

**Step 6 :**
Then right click the layout at the top and then click change layout, then select relative layout and click ok. ( if is already a relative layout skip this step.)

**Step 7 :** 
On the left side of the graphical layout screen, open images and media, then drag and drop your image views to were you would like them. Also note after dragging and dropping your image views you can change there size by right clicking them. then clicking width and typing in a number of your desire, and after the number type dp (no space between it and the number) guess and test is the easiest way to get the right size. Change the height the same way you changed the width, but instead of clicking width click height.

**Step 8 :**
Now I know at this point you probably have pretty much the exact same thing as before, but that is good.

**Step 9 :**
Go over to your package explorer and right click on you layout folder ( not the XML file)
And click copy

**Step 10 :**
Right click on your res folder and click paste

**Step 11 :**
A box is going to pop up do not just hit ok.
Change the writing to layout-small  And then hit ok.

**Step 12 :** 
Open the newly created folder called layout-small and you should see the exact same XML layout file as in your original XML layout. Open the new XML layout file.

**Step 13 :**
The screen size should look like a small screen ( if not go the change screen size and click a small one.)
The layout should look all screwed up.

**Step 14 :**
Do steps 5, 6, and 7 again ( or if have better way of creating layout use that method) Also DO Not Change The Screen Size Make The Layout Look Good At that screen size.
Now the system based on the device will decided what layout to use.

Also if you want to make layouts for large and extra large screens just do steps 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, and 14 again but instead of typing in layout-small in step 11 and make sure you make each layout on appropriate screen size large as a 16" tablet default as a standard phone like a nexus 5 or 4, small as a small phone, and extra large as a large tablet.

> For large type layout-large
>   For extra large type layout-xlarge
>   And medium is the default layout

Also know that this can work for multiple layouts like say you where switching between two layouts you would have 8 layouts two in each folder, if you only had the layout in the default layout folder, it would look the same as it does, but when you switch screen sizes it would be all screwed up.

A good link to look at for this topic :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

try this layout file. it is almost as same as what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="RED"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="25dp"></TextView>




<TextView
    android:text="ORANGE"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffa500"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="25dp"></TextView>




<TextView
    android:text="YELLOW"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="25dp"></TextView>



<TextView
    android:text="GREEN"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView05"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"></TextView>



<TextView
    android:text="BLUE"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00f"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="25dp"></TextView>




<TextView
    android:text="INDIGO"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView05"
    android:background="#4b0082"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"></TextView>



<TextView
    android:text="VIOLET"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ee82ee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="25dp"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**reference : code.tutplus.com**